# how to design a simple one page website

Tags: html, web

i want to design a website who contain 4-5 page but i need a feature then when user click on any link the content is changed without any other page load. how i can do this

my page look like [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html)
but when user click on left side or right side link the content is load without page refresh. how i can do this.

Comment: The page does refresh for me when clicking one of those links.

Comment: only design look like them  page not refreshed when user click on lhs or rhs tab's link

Comment: Don't. Really really don't. The benefits are almost never worth the costs (breaking for users without JS (if you use Ajax), breaking for search engines, breaking bookmarking, complicating printing (if you do use frames), breaking "sending a link to a friend", etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI tabs?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either use frames or load content via Ajax.